# How to match the character '&' and replace it in php

Tags: php, html, regex

My main problem is that some output is coming on the page with a space character written as "`&nbsp;`". I want to replace it back with a space. I tried `str_replace("&nbsp"," ",$mystr)` and even `preg_replace("/(&nbsp;)/", " ", $mystr)` but to no avail. How do I do this? And more generally, if there are other html codes coming as output, like `"&amp;"`, is there a way to replace them with the actual character output instead of the html code?

Edit: Let me clarify a few things here: I don't want people to enter " < s c r i p t > " tags in the source of an editable page. To prevent that, we need some mechanism to escape special characters. But the problem is that some valid characters are also escaped. I want to unescape them, but also want to make sure that no security is breached.

Comment: When you say "coming on the page with a space character written as `"&nbsp;"`" do you mean in the source, or in the browser? If you mean in the source, then my answer's not much good. If you mean in the browser, I think my answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: You may want to replace '&nbsp;', not only '&nbsp'.

Comment: @Kuroki, you might want to try using backticks (`\``) around code.

Answer (score 4):

Are you just doing this?

```
str_replace("&nbsp", " ", $mystr);
```

Or do you do this?

```
$mystr = str_replace("&nbsp", " ", $mystr);
```

Both `str_replace` and `preg_replace` return a value, they don't change the string in-place.

Comment: No, i was doing as you have printed, that is, collecting what was returned as output.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`html_entity_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Comment: That would turn it in a non-breaking space character, not a space.

Comment: I am in a way looking for just that, but am just worried that some function actually does htmlentities() call for me before returning the output. Is it not a security issue to run html_entity_decode on a string? But I am also interested to do it with some regular expression matching.

Comment: -1 It would convert any character reference and not just `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @Gumbo - just re-read the question, and I still think (the original question at least) that's what the OP asked for. Maybe I'm being thick though.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function.

Comment: That would turn it in a non-breaking space character, not a space.

Comment: You can run over the string and replace U+00A0 with U+0020 afterwards.

Comment: This was answer to a second question, about other entities :)

Comment: -1 It would convert any character reference and not just `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 1):

str_replace should replace that part of the text as it doesn't take regular expressions in account, so there is some other problem i guess

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $string = "<p>Hello,& n b s p ;world</p>"; # Remove the spaces here - Stackoverflow bug doesn't let me enter the normal string.
   $string = str_replace("& n b s p ;", " ", $string);
   print $string;
?>
```

This works for me. Perhaps you were expecting it to modify the string in place instead of returning the modified version?

Comment: Tried fixing the source but failed, it appears stackoverflow has a bug!

Comment: This has nothing to do with a "bug" ... &nbsp; is an html entities for a non breakable space so the site displays it as that, obviously. If you add a <a> tag you don't expect the site to display it as-is but to replace it with a link, same thing here ;) You only need to display & with it's own entity (&amp;) to get the expected result: &amp;nbsp;

Comment: @Lepidosteus - That works for normal text but not for code blocks. &amp;nbsp; is rendered as &amp;nbsp; but &nbsp; is rendered as a non-breaking space.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the function you're looking for is https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php urldecode

Comment: The string is encoded with an HTML entity, not URL encoding. And he asked for a space, not the decoded version of the non-breaking space entity.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$text=html_entity_decode(str_replace('& nbsp;',' ',$text));
```

[remove the space between the ampersand and nbsp: it's due to Stack Overflow's formatting]

It'll swap the no-breaking-spaces with normal spaces and then decode any other remaining html entities.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need is an HTML filter based on a proper HTML parser so you can let only specified bits and pieces of HTML be passed through by your script.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). Give it a whitelist of allowed tags/attributes, and it will filter everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since the trailing semicolon may be obmitted, you might want consider using a regular expression:

```
preg_replace("/&nbsp[;]?/", " ", $str)
```

You can replace `[;]?` by `;?`. But Stack Overflow seems to replace `&nbsp‍;` (this is written with a ZERO WIDTH JOINER U+200D) so I used `[;]?`.